# How can I revert an email I've sent in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I understand that once I've sent an email to someone using another service, Gmail has no control over it.

Is it possible to revert an email I've sent to another Gmail address?

Answer (score 13):

Nope. Once a mail has been sent it cannot be revoked via Gmail. However, you can delay sending the mail by up to 30 seconds using the [Gmail Undo Send feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1284885). The undo feature lets you revoke your mail within the time limit you've configured.

Comment: This is has now graduated to be a normal feature of Gmail.